# Convert transformation equation into matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I struggle with, what seems to be, quite easy question and I'm not sure what am I missing.

The question is:

> Let $g\left(\left[\begin{matrix}
> x_1 \\
> x_2
> \end{matrix}\right], \left[\begin{matrix}
> y_1 \\
> y_2
> \end{matrix}\right]\right) = x_1y_1-x_2y_2$. $g$ is a bilinear interpolation. Show the representative matrix $[g]_E$ where $E$ is the standard basis (a.k.a., $E={e_1, e_2}$ for $\mathbb{F}^2$).

The answer to this question is that
$[g]_E=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{matrix}\right]$

But I can't seem to figure our the calculation for that.

As far as I understand, I need to find scalars such that they'll form $g$. But because $g$ has a multiplication ($x_1y_1$ and $x_2y_2$) I'm not sure how to find such scalars and why is the answer correct.

Comment: You’re looking for a matrix $M$ such that $[\mathbf v_1]_E^TM[\mathbf v_2]_E$ produces the required expression.

Comment: Note in the answer you stated, the $g_{ij}$ values of the answer about the representative matrix correspond to $\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 x_i y_j$ of your $g$ function. In particular, $g_{11} = 1$ corresponds to $x_1 y_1$ and $g_{22} = -1$ corresponds to $-x_2 y_2$, with the $2$ zero values corresponding the absence of those terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a matrix $A$ such that $\vec{x}A\vec{y}=G(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ Thanks to bilinearity, you can get your matrix in a simple way, as $A_{ij} = G(\vec{e}_i, \vec{e}_j)$

In your case:

$G((1,0), (1,0)) = 1$

$G((1,0), (0,1)) = 0$

$G((0,1), (1,0)) = 0$

$G((0,1), (0,1)) = -1$